# Is there a condition where a node in a javaFX scene will not be shown?

Tags: javafx, layout

I decided to create a JavaFX calculator that includes `Button`s and `Label`s and a `Pane` as my root `Parent`.

I'm still stuck with the layout, here is a rough sketch of the expected result:

[image: sketch]

Bear with my poor graphics.

**The problem is that I see a blank screen when I run the following code:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

/**
* This class is meant to serve as a simple calculator with basic funtions
* to try myself out with javafx 
*/
public class CalculatorFX extends Application{
    Label question; // This is the label that shows the question
    Label answer; // This is the label that shows the answer
    Button[] buttons = new Button[19]; // This is the buttons of the calculator
    
    /**
    * This is the root parent or container. It is defined out here because
    * I hope to know its length and width are crucial for the layout. 
    */
    Pane root = new Pane();

    /**
    * This is the length of the Pane
    */
    double rootHeight = root.getHeight();
    
    /**
    * This is the width of the Pane 
    */
    double rootWidth = root.getWidth();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    /**
    * This start routine sets up the GUI 
    */
    public void start(Stage stage){
        question = new Label("Type your question");
        answer = new Label("Answer:");
        question.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
        question.setFont( Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 18) );
        question.setStyle("-fx-font: 15pt sans-serif; -fx-padding: 7px; -fx-border-color: darkred; -fx-border-width: 2px; -fx-text-fill: darkred; -fx-background-color: pink; ");
        
        /* Initializing the numerical buttons first using a loop */
        // for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        //     buttons[i] = new Button(i + "");
        // }
        /* They are configured like this in the way, they would appear on
        * the parent node */
        buttons[0] = new Button("CLEAR");
        buttons[1] = new Button("DEL");
        buttons[2] = new Button("CONT");
        buttons[3] = new Button("7");
        buttons[4] = new Button("8");
        buttons[5] = new Button("9");
        buttons[6] = new Button("*");
        buttons[7] = new Button("4");
        buttons[8] = new Button("5");
        buttons[9] = new Button("6");
        buttons[10] = new Button("/");
        buttons[11] = new Button("1");
        buttons[12] = new Button("2");
        buttons[13] = new Button("3");
        buttons[14] = new Button("-");
        buttons[15] = new Button("0");
        buttons[16] = new Button(".");
        buttons[17] = new Button("=");
        buttons[18] = new Button("+");

        /* Here we set the position of the children */
        double unitX = rootWidth/4;
        double unitY = rootHeight/9;
        double nextX = rootWidth;
        double nextY = rootHeight;
        for(int lineNum = 6; lineNum >= 0; lineNum--){
            nextY = nextY - unitY;
            nextX = rootWidth - unitX;
            for(int element = 4; element >=0 ; element--){
                if(lineNum == 1){// Then we need to fill the lines
                    if( element == 1)
                        continue;
                    //buttons[lineNum + element + 8].relocate(nextX, nextY);
                }
                if(lineNum == 0){
                    answer.relocate(0, nextY - unitY);
                    System.out.println("Relocated answer label");
                    question.relocate(0,0);
                    System.out.println("Relocated answer label");
                    break; // This breaks out of two for loops because
                    // this is the last lineNum.
                }
                //buttons[lineNum + element + 8].relocate(nextX, nextY);
                nextX = nextX - unitX;
            }
        }

        /* There is also a need to resize the children */
        question.setManaged(false);
        question.resize(rootWidth, 2*unitY);
        System.out.println("Resized label question");
        answer.setManaged(false);
        answer.resize(rootWidth, 2*unitY);
        System.out.println("Resized label answer");
        // for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        //     buttons[i].setManaged(false);
        //     buttons[i].resize(unitX, unitY);
        // }

        /* Time to configure them on our root */
        root.setPrefWidth(400);
        root.setPrefHeight(800);
        root.getChildren().addAll(question, answer);
        // for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        //    root.getChildren().add(buttons[i]);
        // }

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("myStyle.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("CalculatorFX");
        stage.show();

    } // End of start
} // End of class CalculatorFX
```

Now, `myStyle.css` contains:

```
Button { 
    -fx-font: bold 16pt "Times New Roman"; 
    -fx-text-fill: darkblue; 
}
Label { 
    -fx-font: 15pt sans-serif; 
    -fx-padding: 7px; 
    -fx-border-color: darkred; 
    -fx-border-width: 2px; 
    -fx-text-fill: darkred; 
    -fx-background-color: pink; 
}
```

Help me. Why do I see a blank screen?

Comment: The width and height of the `root` will be zero when you call `root.getWidth()` and `root.getHeight()`. Why are you trying to do all the layout yourself, instead of using a layout pane?

Comment: You are doing **way** too much work yourself on laying out your UI! JavaFX has many built-in tools to help you lay things out exactly how you want them, without doing the calculations yourself. Check out the [Working With Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) tutorial to learn more.

Comment: Additionally, if you did need to manage layout yourself (which you definitely don’t need to do here), you would be doing it in the wrong place. The correct way to define your own layout is to subclass `Pane` and override `layoutChildren()` (and often other methods).

Answer (score 0):

### To answer your main question:

#### Yes there is!

In JavaFX, `Node`s have [visible property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#visibleProperty):

> Specifies whether this `Node` and any subnodes should be rendered as part of the scene graph.

You control it using the [setVisible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setVisible-boolean-) method.

### To help you get started:

As [Zephyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6485651/zephyr) and [Jamed_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6485651/zephyr) pointed out, you are doing too much work.

I believe there are several correct ways to go about what you are trying to achieve.
A visual editor like [SceneBuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) comes to mind. It could help you get a deeper understanding of JavaFX's components. Especially, if building the GUI programmatically is not a must for you.

**Here is a simple example to help you get started with one of the ways:**

```
public class App extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {

    var label1 = new Label("Type your question: ");
    var label2 = new Label("Answer: ");
    label1.setPrefHeight(40);
    label2.setPrefHeight(40);
    label1.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
    label2.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
    HBox label1HB = new HBox(label1);
    HBox label2HB = new HBox(label2);

    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.setFillWidth(true);
    vBox.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    vBox.setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(label1HB, label2HB);

    List<HBox> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
      HBox hbox = new HBox();
      for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
        Button button = new Button(row + " " + col);
        button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        button.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
        hbox.getChildren().add(button);
      }
      VBox.setVgrow(hbox, Priority.ALWAYS);
      rows.add(hbox);
    }
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(rows);
    // Uncomment the following line to see the visible property in action.
    // rows.get(2).setVisible(false);
    var scene = new Scene(vBox, 400, 800);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

}
```

[image]

I personally like wrapping my nodes within a `VBox` or an `Hbox` because it allows me to change the scene's size without worrying about resizing everything again.

[image]

You can find many tutorials online explaining how to exploit different JavaFX layouts' properties to achieve better as well as cleaner GUI and code.

It should be mentioned that you are going to have to take care of:

- A couple of issues, like what happens when the window is too small to fit your entire content?
- Some specifics, like if you want some of your nodes to have a fixed width and height.
- etc.

Comment: hard-coding any of the min/max/pref is .. evil, always ;) Maxing them out might be okay in some contexts, using a specific double size certainly will break the layout, f.i.  when changing device/-resolution, font, localization .. do-not-do-it!

Comment: @kleopatra I never thought of it that way! Could you elaborate on that a little bit more? Wouldn't wanna keep doing devilish behaviours ;P...